# How to deploy to WebSphere Liberty apps directory from WebSphere Liberty Maven plugin?

Tags: maven, ant, maven-plugin, websphere-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

I have a application running in WebSphere liberty. Through **mvn install** command I need to deploy my application to liberty **apps** directory as I am not using **dropins** directory.

Bellow is the working maven plugin code from which I can deploy to **dropins** directory.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-server</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <verifyTimeout>60</verifyTimeout>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <serverHome>${wlp.dir}</serverHome>
                <serverName>${server}</serverName>
                <appArtifact>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                </appArtifact>
                <appDeployName>${project.artifactId}.${project.packaging}</appDeployName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I couldn't find anywhere what configuration need to be added/change to deploy application directly to apps directory. Can someone please let me know what is missing here?

Comment: Based on the github repo doc (https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven/blob/master/docs/deploy.md#deploy) it sounds like it's only possible to deploy to `dropins`.  Why do you need to deploy to the `apps` directory instead of `dropins`?  Shared lib or something?

Comment: Yes. I cannot have shared lib and it cause some issues in my application. Therefore I have no choice but to go with apps directory

Comment: You can apply shared libs to "dropin apps" by putting jars in this location: `${shared.config.dir}/lib/global` or `${server.config.dir}/lib/global`.  See this doc: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html

Comment: I was using ${shared.config.dir}/lib/global until I hit the error oracle/sql/ArrayDescriptor. It was causing from ojdbc6.jar. Once I put application in apps folder and assigned libs dir configuration to application manually in server.xml and use the same libs dir configuration in server.xml for creating the dataSource, issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Adding **install-apps** execution step instead **deploy**(deploy execution step will deploy application to dropins folder only) step will resolve the issue. **Version had to be updated to 1.3** which is the latest as of now

Ref : https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven/blob/master/docs/install-apps.md

Full maven plugin code will be as bellow

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>start-server</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>start-server</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <verifyTimeout>60</verifyTimeout>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>install-apps</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-apps</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <appsDirectory>apps</appsDirectory>
                    <installAppPackages>project</installAppPackages>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <serverHome>${wlp.dir}</serverHome>
            <serverName>${server}</serverName>
            <appArtifact>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>${project.packaging}</type>
            </appArtifact>
            <appDeployName>${project.artifactId}.${project.packaging}</appDeployName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the current 2.0-SNAPSHOT version of the plugin. Just include the parent pom and a little piece of configuration for the plugin. Version 2.0 will be released in early June.

If you don't want to include the parent pom, you can just copy the `<pluginManagement/>` section from the parent pom which contains the binding of the liberty-maven-plugin goals to the Maven default build lifecycle.  See https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven/blob/master/docs/parent-pom.md

```
<parent>
    <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>liberty-maven-app-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/
        </url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/
        </url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
         </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

...

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <assemblyArtifact>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.runtime</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wlp-webProfile7</artifactId>
                    <version>17.0.0.1</version>
                    <type>zip</type>
                </assemblyArtifact>
                <serverName>${project.artifactId}Server</serverName>
                <configFile>src/main/liberty/config/server.xml</configFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    ...
</build>
```